# Grouped densities over histogram - how to remove density marker from legend? (Ggplot, R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

Reproducible example:

```
require(ggplot2)

mtcars$am2 <- factor(mtcars$am)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = ..density.., fill = am2)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.8, colour = 1, bins = 12)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c( "pink", "lightgrey")) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )

p1 +
  geom_density(colour = "blue", lwd = 2, inherit.aes = F, aes(x = mpg, y = ..density.., group = am2))
```

I would like to remove the thick blue border from around the squares representing the colours in the legend. (In my real data this makes sense, the two densities don't overlap.) I have tried to play with `legend.key =` this and that in `theme()`, but nothing seems to take effect. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `show.legend=FALSE` in your `geom_density` call to remove the blue border in your legend like this:

```r
mtcars$am2 <- factor(mtcars$am)
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = ..density.., fill = am2)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.8, colour = 1, bins = 12)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c( "pink", "lightgrey")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") 

p1 +
  geom_density(colour = "blue", lwd = 2, inherit.aes = F, aes(x = mpg, y = ..density.., group = am2), show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Add `show_guide = FALSE` in `geom_density`:

```
mtcars$am2 <- factor(mtcars$am)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = ..density.., fill = am2)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.8, colour = 1, bins = 12)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c( "pink", "lightgrey")) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )

p1 +
  geom_density(colour = "blue", lwd = 2, inherit.aes = F, show_guide = FALSE, aes(x = mpg, y = ..density.., group = am2))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Shubham - I have already accepted Quinten's response, who replied first, but I do appreciate you taking the trouble to help.

Comment: Always good to look for multiple options, but please not that `show_guide` has been deprecated.